# Remove prefix string# from list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How can I remove prefix string#? from list using calculation field.

How can I remove prefix string#? from list using calculation field.
I have column [Nazwa klienta] - this is a calculated column. To this column I put two others columns [Nazwa] and [SAN] - those columns are in other site.

I use this formula:

```
=[Nazwa]&" "&"("&[SAN]&")"
```

to receive

```
Nazwa_klienta (SAN000000)
```

After that, I create a site columns and use like a reference and use in other list.
Do I need to create two columns? One for the reference column and second for the calculated field?

[image: string# list]

To be clearly - this **STRING;#** shows only when I using Word (when I try to pick up a client).

Comment: You're going to have to start Accepting answers if you want people to spend their own time to help you - see FAQ top right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your field is called [MyField] you would setup a calculated column with the following formula

```
=MID([MyField],9,LEN(MyField))
```

*(9 because you want to start at the 9th character, "string;#" has 8 characters)*

Comment: I have join the two columns in one:  
=[Nazwa]&" "&"("&[SAN]&")"  
After that, when I want to choose this field in Word, I've got this:  
string;#.......  Did I need next column to use your formula?

Comment: eh? I don't understand you - is this a clarification to your question? In that case update your question and put ALL the details in it.

Comment: Sorry for this uncleanly message. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using the SharePoint-Online and Office-365 tags, it's like this answer isn't applicable, however the string# issue can be related to a Office 2007 client bug - [details here](http://sympmarc.com/2008/08/13/string-before-values-in-a-sharepoint-lists-lookup-column-based-on-a-calculated-value/). The [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948952) outlines the symptoms and rather than installing the hotfix, I've requested Office 2007 SP3 for the user to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In c# code, it looks like using `SPField.GetFieldValueAsText` return a the value without the extra prefix characters.